# Upload multiple files with the same file name into the library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, libraries

Probably this is a bit of a noob question, but... Is there any way to upload multiple files with the same name into the same library without use of folders (which are evil in SP :) )? My understanding is that this is not possible, but maybe I can do it if I somehow leverage some other unique column which SP will take into account along with file name so that name match won't present an issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.

If you have versioning disabled in the document library, the new file will replace the old.

If you have versioning enabled in the document library, the new file will be added as a version of the old.

You *could* develop an `item adding` event receiver that checks the file name and changes it if duplicates are found, but I don't think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: But with folders I can have duplicate names, right? (one per folder and one in root) Could be the same achieved with use of Document Sets instead of folders?

Comment: Yes, one file in each folder. You have to remember files in a document library all have a URL to them. If you had two files with the same name in the same folder you couldn't have unique URLs for files in document libraries. Document sets are just glorified folders.